# Dynamic link creation in PHP and Mysql from more than one table

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner in PHP. I have created a search bar for a website. But i have no clue how to create a dynamic link for the results. I am able to fetch the data from around 4-5 tables. how to create a dynamic link for 4 tables(mysql).

Thanks in advance.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
$query = $_GET['query'];       
$min_length = 3;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
     $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
     $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
     $sql = mysql_query(
           "SELECT id,title,brief,description,time,image1 
            FROM news 
            WHERE (`brief` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            UNION 
            SELECT id,title,brief,description,time,image1 
            FROM articles 
            WHERE (`brief` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%')  
            UNION 
            SELECT id,title,brief,description,time,image1 
            FROM interview 
            WHERE (`brief` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            UNION 
            SELECT id,title,NULL,description,NULL,NULL 
            FROM academy 
            WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%') 
            ORDER BY id DESC ")  
           or die(mysql_error());

     if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){ 
         while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
             echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3><br>".$results['brief']."".$results['time']."</p>";
         }
     } else { 
         echo "No Results Found";
     }

} else {
     echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to properly format your code.  If we can't read this, we won't help you.  :-(

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just fyi `mysql` is deprecated, you should be using `mysqli` and always take in consideration how prone your code is to sql injection

Comment: Be handy if you formatted it so that you could read it as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help James. I am new to php and stack overflow as well.I will learn asap.

Comment: What type of url you are looking for? Give an example of that url.

Comment: @Basha I see you are iterating through your results to create some text inside `<p>` tags. Why dont you create your links inside the `while` loop just like youre doing your text?

Comment: What do you mean by **a dynamic link** can you give a simple example of what you would like to happen please. Do you mean a clickable link on the web page? If so what do you want the link to do??

Comment: @Riggs Folly, Chayan I have created a search bar for a website. For Example, if a person search for racing academy in our website, it will show the result title and brief not full content. I have achieved that. if the user click on  title(as link), it should go to the related page dynamically  to view the  full content of the PHP page(example : article or news).

Comment: Where is your url link stored..?  (also, dont put a `<h3>` inside a `<p>`)

Comment: @MaggsWeb, URL has to be created dynamically once the user click on title using id from Mysql tables. Example, search result stored in 4 different tables as title1 with table 1 title2 with table 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your article URL should look like this: "http://websiteurl.com/category(news,articles)/123(product-id)/short-title-for-seo".
I'd recommand you to put the id of the selected material and the category as the main filter when showing the content.
To get the table name (or to convert the table name to a category alias) you can do something like this: 
SELECT 'table1' as tableName from table1

Answer (score 0):

First thing to know is if you want to display a dynamic data from database, you have to store a url for a perticular `$result['title']` which has to be wrapped around an anchor tag `<a>`. 
For example: `<?php echo '<a href='.$result['url'].'><h3>'.$result['title'].'</h3></a>';?>`

Or some part of the url can be hard coded and point to the title's id in the last part of the url. 
For example:`<?php echo '<a href=http://www.your-domain/content/index.php?id='.$result['id'].'><h3>'.$result['title'].'</h3></a>';`

Later you must create a new page which `$_GET`s the slug from the url and display the description or full details.

Comment: Thank you Kirs Sudh. I am able to generate the dynamic links now.